# os_log: Unexpected value for integer in Console.app and in `log stream`

Tags: ios, swift, macos, logging, foundation

**Code** (Swift 3):

```
os_log("State changed: from %d to %d", 1, 2)
```

**Xcode 8** (Debug Area Console):

`2016-10-01 00:38:55.903298 AUHost[82455:1512026] State changed: from 1 to 2`

**Terminal** (log stream):

`2016-10-01 00:38:54.880763+0200 0x17125a   Default     0x8000000000022d5e   82455  AUHost: State changed: from 1 to 1718550530`

**Console.app**:

`State changed: from 1 to 1718550530`

Why **Console.app** and command **log stream** shows unexpected value **1718550530** instead of **2**?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**:

Unexpected behaviour observed when **even** number of arguments is used:

```
os_log("View loaded: %d", 1)
os_log("View loaded: %d => %d", 1, 2)
os_log("View loaded: %d => %d => %d", 1, 2, 3)
os_log("View loaded: %d => %d => %d => %d", 1, 2, 3, 4)
os_log("View loaded: %d => %d => %d => %d => %d", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Output:

```
View loaded: 1
View loaded: 1 => 1718550530
View loaded: 1 => 2 => 3
View loaded: 1 => 2 => 3 => 1718550532
View loaded: 1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 5
```

Looks like a bug. Reported to Apple: https://openradar.appspot.com/28574572

Comment: 1718550530's lower 16 bits are 0000 0000 0000 0010 (= 2), and 1718550532's lower 16 bits are 0000 0000 0000 0100 (= 4).

Comment: True. Does it means that we need to "transform/flip/shift" original value before submit to logging stream?

Comment: Have you tried deliberately making all the numbers Int32? EDIT: That doesn't fix it. This definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: Also tried to use different formatters and cast to C-types (i.e. CInt, CLong https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html). Does not help .(

Comment: It works fine from Objective-C, though. Definitely looks like a bug using os_log() with Swift. I'll file a separate bug, referencing yours.

Comment: So does this repeatedly work correct when you have an odd number of arguments? Or you've ran into issues with that as well?

Comment: In macOS 10.12.6 (16G29), Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b) or Xcode 9.0 beta 4 (9M189t) issue seems gone.

Comment: Oh....I am working on a legacy Swift 2.3 Xcode 8.2.1...And how about the other issue where you were getting private for printing strings...is that also resolved?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, but the correct format would be `%ld` because an `Int` can be 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: _And how about the other issue where you were getting private for printing strings...is that also resolved_ -> Dynamic strings with `%{public}@` modifier still not "reliable" listed in macOS Console.app. Randomly logs appears. But not all the time. Static strings seems working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (2020-07-21), in Swift 5.something and Xcode 11.6, I'm still encountering this issue when using os_log in an iOS app.

It's not a full fix, but a workaround that was effective for me was to cast the incoming `Int` into a `String` before the `os_log()` call (not forgetting to change the format token to `%@`):

```
let intA = 7
let intB = 4
os_log("State changed: from %@ to %@", String(intA), String(intB))
```